# Jax Ws based Projekt: Error:package javax.jws does not exist ; Programm cannot find symbols

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio, web-services, error-handling

as the title states, i do get the two following Errors:
1.package javax.jws does not exist
2.cannot find symbol for example **@WebService, Endpoint.publish**

Here is the structure of the Projekt:
[Strukture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC5sN.png)

The four Code Files:
1. HalloWelt.java:

```
package miniwebservice;

import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
public interface HalloWelt
{
   public String hallo( @WebParam( name = "wer" ) String wer );
}
```

2.HalloWeltImpl.java:

```
package miniwebservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService( endpointInterface="miniwebservice.HalloWelt" )
public class HalloWeltImpl implements HalloWelt
{
   public String hallo( String wer )
   {
      return "Hallo " + wer;
   }
}
```

3.TestWsClient.java:

```
package miniwebservice;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class TestWsClient
{
   public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Throwable
   {
      String url = ( args.length > 0 ) ? args[0] : "http://localhost:4434/miniwebservice";
      Service service = Service.create(
            new URL( url + "?wsdl" ),
            new QName( "http://miniwebservice/", "HalloWeltImplService" ) );
      HalloWelt halloWelt = service.getPort( HalloWelt.class );
      System.out.println( "\n" + halloWelt.hallo( args.length > 1 ? args[1] : "" ) );
   }
}
```

4.TestWsServer.java:

```
package miniwebservice;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class TestWsServer
{
   public static void main( final String[] args )
   {
      String url = ( args.length > 0 ) ? args[0] : "http://localhost:4434/miniwebservice";
      Endpoint.publish( url, new HalloWeltImpl() );
   }
}
```

By Doing the following: javac -d bin src/miniwebservice/*.java
I get those Errors: [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbXQk.png)

What is the issue? And how can i solve it?

Comment: *"What is the issue?"* You didn't add the necessary web service jar files to the classpath. Take another look at whatever tutorial you're following, to make sure you setup the project type / classpath correctly.

Comment: I did everything as the tutorial states, but there are still this errors. How do i add service jar files to the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the Java Servlet API jar in your classpath, but don't have it. Here's a link to download the latest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1

You didn't mention how you're running your program, so you'll want to add the downloaded jar to your classpath either through your IDE (looks like VSCode) or via the command line with `java TestWsClient -cp java.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar`.

Comment: Runing Program through VS Console, also tried CMD -> same errors. how can i add Java Servlet API jar to classpath?

Comment: @Roman Download the jar file from the link I provided, stick it in the same directory as your .java files, and run the command I provided.